# Any simpler GAS code to remove partial filename between a special char and file extension period symbol?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I want my script to be able to remove the additional substrings and/ special characters (between last space after the filename " - " and the last "." before the file extension) in the filename (in gdrive) whenever user upload their files via my google form. Final output must be *filename.extension*. Original filename could possibly have space and dash symbols too, but the script will just slice out as long as it finds match of the first space-dash-space until the last period symbol regardless whichever in between.

```
var oldFile="abcd filename - Code Tester.jpeg"; 
//original and expected filename in gdrive is "abcd filename.jpeg"
```

So far, below is what I have tried :

```
var newFile=oldFile.slice(0,oldFile.indexOf(' - '))+oldFile.slice(oldFile.lastIndexOf('.'));
var oldFileID=oldFile.getId();
oldFile=DriveApp.getFileById(oldFileID);
oldFile.setName(newFile); //"abcd filename - Code Tester.jpeg" is renamed as "abcd filename.jpeg"
```

Is there any simpler way to have the same output, please?

Appreciate your expertise. Thanks. DZ

Comment: You may want to specify exactly what characters may appear in place of ` - Code Tester`. Is it always a space dash space followed by uppercase and lowercase letters and spaces, and nothing else before the period right before the file extension?

Comment: You're right. I didn't think of that earlier. Actually this string ``` - Code Tester``` is auto-added based on the First Name and Last Name that the user's set in the gmail when our gform is in a subdirectory. Your solution unfortunately won't work if there's extras of " - " and "." in between and won't replace anything if special chars (as this is allowed in First and Last Name of gmail)

Comment: I have edited my question to add more info on the exact output I would expect.

Comment: Edited the regex and the replacement string in the answer to reflect the new information regarding filename structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `oldFile` is an instance of a `File` object, try this:

```
oldFile.setName(oldFile.getName().replace(/(.+) - .+?\.(\w+)$/, '$1.$2'));
```

Comment: In words find a space a dash another space then one or more characters that aren't dashes follow by a period and replace that with a period.  Could that be `/ - [^.]+/`?  Maybe it has to be escaped.

Comment: @Cooper yours is replaced with "undefined" and not full removal if there's repetitive " - " and "." in between.

Comment: @doubleunary, perfecto! Tqvm!